# iOS Framework - get plist into a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am creating an iOS - framework (swift)
I have this function - which I am using for retrieving a dictionary that should hold all of the lib properties (strings)

```
func getPropertyList() -> [String: Any]?{
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "properties", ofType: "plist")!
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: Any]
    return dict
}
```

from test this line keep returning nil

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "properties", ofType: "plist")!
```

even though the properties.plist file is inside the 'copy Bundle Resources'
and the target membership is selected

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
let path = Bundle(identifier:"com.example.frameworkID")!.path(forResource: "properties", ofType: "plist")!
```